# How to know when was the last time I changed the time zone?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, timezone, clock

I changed my time zone recently but can't recall which day. Is there a way to know what is the date that I changed my time zone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For systemd based distros: `journalctl | grep systemd-timedated` will show all the timezone changes granted the logs are still there
- For distros similar to Fedora and Arch running `ls -l /etc/localtime` could show the date the file was last modified. Ubuntu and Debian based distros use `/etc/timezone` instead.